# How to estimate the absolute expected difference?

Tags: random-variable, unbiased-estimator

Suppose we have two random variables $X$ and $Y$ with unknown distributions. I am looking for an unbiased estimator for the absolute expected difference:
$$
| E \{ X - Y \} | .
$$
For instance, suppose we have unbiased independent observations $x_1, \ldots, x_n$ and $y_1, \ldots, y_m$ ($n,m \geq 1$), how can we use these data to construct an unbiased estimator for the above quantity?

Preferably, I would like to find an unbiased estimator for the general case, including perhaps only mild assumptions such as the existence of the first (few) moment(s). However, I am happy with any progress including:

- solutions for specific distributions with unknown parameters (e.g., under the assumption that $X$ and $Y$ are both distributed according to a normal distribution, but the means and variances are unknown),
- efficient biased estimators, for instance that minimize the mean squared error (again, suggestions for the general case and for specific distributions are welcome), and
- any thoughts on good estimators for special cases.

Thanks for any input!

Comment: Are you looking for it to never be biased in all cases, on average, or in a specific case?

Comment: Is there any reason you suspect the absolute value of the obvious estimator for $E[X-Y]$ would be biased?

Comment: If you plug in sample means for $X$ and $Y$ you will get a consistent estimator. Take for simplicity $m=n=1$: $E|x_1 - y_1| \geq |Ex_1 - Ey_1| = |\mu_x - \mu_y|$ the bias indeed is present, but I think it is crucial only in very small samples...

Comment: @Peter I've merged your two accounts. You can now use [the one](http://stats.stackexchange.com/users/6087/peter) that you registered.

Comment: Thanks, chl! @Dmitrij The sample means would indeed be consistent, but I was hoping for something a little bit better. In my case, the sample sizes are often small and additionally the bias may be cumulative... For those reasons, I would even be interested in less efficient estimators (i.e., with higher variance) that may reduce the bias. Any thoughts?

Comment: A little more explicitly, as @Dmitrij points out, the plug-in estimator will *always* be biased (upward). This result follows directly from Jensen's inequality, i.e., $\mathbb{E}|\bar{X}-\bar{Y}| \geq |\mathbb{E} (\bar{X}-\bar{Y})| = |\mu_X - \mu_Y|$.

Comment: Why do you want an _unbiased_ estimator?

Comment: @Karl Sometimes the bias of several estimators can be cumulative. Roughly speaking, the error I'm trying to minimize is a weighted MSE, where there is more weight on the bias than on the variance. If no unbiased estimators are known, I'm also very interested in biased estimators with lower bias than the difference in sample means $|\bar{X}-\bar{Y}|$. For instance, if $a < 1$, $|a\bar{X}-a\bar{Y}|=a|\bar{X}-\bar{Y}|$ might result in a bias that is sometimes negative, resulting in a lower bias for the sum of such estimates. But then the question is how to choose $a$?

Comment: To expand the last example a little further, in some cases $|\bar{X} - \bar{Y}|$ is unbiased and $a$ should be equal to one. This happens when $P(X > Y) = 1$ or when $P(X > Y) = 0$. So perhaps I could use an estimate for $P(X > Y)$ in some way to reduce the bias? I'll continue thinking about this. Any input is very welcome.

Comment: If I am not mistaken, note that $|\bar{X} - \bar{Y}|$ is unbiased for $|\mu_X - \mu_Y|$ if and only if $\bar{X} \geq \bar{Y} \,\mathrm{a.s.}$ or $\bar{Y} \geq \bar{X} \,\mathrm{a.s.}$ and this happens if and only if $X \geq Y \,\mathrm{a.s.}$ or $Y \geq X \,\mathrm{a.s.}$. (The example you've given is a subcase of this.) Is this really a possibility in your application? What other properties of the distributions do you know, or are you trying to keep it completely nonparametric?

Comment: @cardinal In my application typically not much is known a priori about the distributions of $X$ and $Y$. It may be possible that $X \geq Y$ a.s., but even if this is the case we will usually not know this beforehand. In some cases $X$ and $Y$ are known to be approximately normal. Often the overlap in distributions is considerable, which unfortunately implies a reasonably large bias for the estimator $|\bar{X}-\bar{Y}|$.

Comment: There seem to be some discrepancies between the question asked and the comments.  Is it an estimator for $\vert E[X-Y]\vert$ that is desired (as in the question) or an estimator for $E\vert X - Y\vert ]$?  It is not obvious to me that $\vert E[X-Y]\vert = \vert E[X] - E[Y]\vert = \vert \mu_X - \mu_Y \vert$ is the same as $E\vert X - Y\vert ]$.

Comment: @Dilip I was looking for an estimator for $| E \{ X - Y \}|$, as in the question. There may be some confusion, because we discussed the estimator $|\bar{X} - \bar{Y}|$, which is unbiased for $E \{ |X - Y| \}$, but not for $| E \{ X - Y \} |$. Knowing that it is biased, my concern was whether it would be 'good enough', or whether a 'better' estimator for $| E \{ X - Y \}|$ exists. Of course, this depends on the application. In my setting, some increase in variance is okay if I can get the bias down, so right now I'm experimenting with bootstrap approaches, as in the answer by Aniko below.

Comment: @Peter, $|\bar{X}-\bar{Y}|$ is not unbiased for $\mathbb E|X-Y|$ either, and for the same reason. :)

Answer (score 2):

Bootstrap bias correction was invented to adjusted for bias in the estimation of $f(Z)$ (my $Z$ is your $X-Y$). The idea is very simple: create $B$ bootstrap resamples from your data, and calculate $f_b=f(Z_b)$ for each one of them. Then the bootrstrap estimate of the bias is $\bar{f_b}-f(Z)$, where $\bar{f_b}$  is the average of $f_b$'s. Finally, subtract this bias from $f(Z)$ do get the bias corrected estimate $2f(Z) - \bar{f}_b$.

This estimate is unbiased, but has much more variance then the uncorrected estimate.

The reference for bootstrap methods including this bias correction is: Efron, Tibshirani 'An introduction to the bootstrap' (1993), Chapman & Hall.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I had heard about bootstrapping, but have not yet read the paper by Efron and Tibshirani. However, contrary to your claim, it seems this estimate is not unbiased. Where did you get that claim from? Do you perhaps mean that it is asymptotically consistent?

Comment: I'll have to check on the unbiasedness part.